# Cannot get any archetypes from Maven when using the remote catalog URL

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven

I'm trying to create a new Maven project but I can't. I tried the command line and also through Eclipse.

The error I get when trying to use the command line is along the lines of

> [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the
>    plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the
>   repositories [local (C:\Users\MY_NAME.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
>
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>
> [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException

After searching around for the solution to the error, the problem seems to occur because I'm behind a firewall/proxy here at work.

I was then advised to go into Eclipse and try adding the remote catalog URL to Eclipse. What I done was I went to Windows > Preferences > Maven > Archetypes > Add Remote Catalog. I then put it `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml` for the "Catalog File" field and `maven catalog` for the "Description" field.

I then click Verify to see if it was working and I got a warning saying that the "Remote catalog is empty".

I went ahead and tried to create a new Maven project anyway. After filling out my `groupId` and all that, I click finish. Another error comes up saying

> Could not resolve archetype
>
> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:1.0 form any of the configured repositories.

How do I get around this?

Comment: Are you able to get to `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml` using your browser. This will help determine if it is a firewall problem

Comment: @jr593 I can access that URL in my browser with no problem.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala I solved this by using the repo in the UK. Try this https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html

Answer (score 6):

I fixed it today by firstly downloading the file in the browser then adding it as local file

Comment: I downloaded and saved the archtype-catalog file in local. Tried to give local path. Pressed the 'verify' button on the pop up wehere we give this path. It  stillsays 'Remote catalog is empty'

Comment: @VDevD In this case can you confirm if you are trying to add a locare catalof instead of remote catalog ?

Answer (score 1):

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml  is the "given" link to get access the the remote archetype.

However it may be outdated.  You need to include http (s) therefore https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml
is what is required to get the remote archetypes to appear in eclipse or your favorite browser.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it today by firstly downloading the file in the browser then adding it as local file.
You need to include http (s) 
Try the below link:-
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml

Answer (score 1):

Remote url should be
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml

instead

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml

it worked for me in 2021 Jan

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add archetype catalog, you can use the Remote archetype catalog.

Old links which are shared are not working

Use - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.  I downloaded and saved the archtype-catalog xml file to local drive and then added using "Add Local Catalog".

Answer (score -2):

just look at the address
you havnt put https 
***https://repo1.maven.apache.org/maven2***
try this it will halpful to